# Phpunit setup function calling multiple times while executing the test

Tags: phpunit

Setup function call multiple time. I need to execute only once. I am new to the phpunit.can anyone give the solution for this.I need to execute 4 tests in this file and i need to use the same variable name

```
class XSCBookModelTest extends TestCase
{
    public $categoryID;
    public $categoryName = "Motivations";
    public $parentID = 0;

    protected function setUp()
    { 
        $this->XSCBooksModelObj = new XSCBooksModel();

        $categoryObjModel = new XSCCategoryModel();

        $this->categoryID = $categoryObjModel->AddCategory($this->categoryName, $this->parentID);
        $this->setup = 0;

        $this->assertNotEquals($this->categoryID, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`setUp()` is supposed to be called once before each test method, see the [documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.5/fixtures.html) for details.

Comment: If i need to call the function only once for whole test class ,which function i need to to use.

Comment: @Kavitha In that case you would use `setUpBeforeClass()`